# getting a specific value from JSON.parse() javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Hello I am trying to figure out how to get the "changes" value from
`{ data: { sequenceStart: 1613141716565, symbol: 'KCS-BTC', changes: { asks: [Array], bids: [] }, sequenceEnd: 1613141716565 }, subject: 'trade.l2update', topic: '/market/level2:KCS-BTC', type: 'message' }`

The data is stored in let data = JSON.parse(msg)

I have tried console.log(data.data.changes) but get undefined, im lost because console.log(data.data) seems to get me part way there but not when I add .changes?

Comment: Can you make sure that the response is in correct json format? If it is a string then it wont work. You can use firebug4 console to see the format

Comment: Can you also check the typo (the spelling for changes is correct)

Comment: var grr = data.data
  console.log(typeof grr) returns it being an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check my code below.
I think your msg is not formated correctly , you can compare with my code

```html
<body >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

   var msg = '{"data": { "sequenceStart": "1613141716565", "symbol": "KCS-BTC", "changes": { "asks":[["0","0","1613141798456"]],"bids":[]}, "sequenceEnd": 1613141716565 }, "subject": "trade.l2update", "topic": "/market/level2:KCS-BTC", "type": "message" }';
   var data  = JSON.parse(msg);
   console.log(data.data.changes);  
   
   var msg1 = '{"sequenceStart":1613141798456,"symbol":"KCS-BTC","changes":{"asks":[["0","0","1613141798456"]],"bids":[]},"sequenceEnd":1613141798456}';
   var data1  = JSON.parse(msg1);
   console.log(data1.changes);  

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: this is the un parsed message I get back from kucoin {"data":{"sequenceStart":1613141798456,"symbol":"KCS-BTC","changes":{"asks":[["0","0","1613141798456"]],"bids":[]},"sequenceEnd":1613141798456},"subject":"trade.l2update","topic":"/market/level2:KCS-BTC","type":"message"}

Comment: From the above message , It is in a wrong json format. If msg = `{"sequenceStart":1613141798456,"symbol":"KCS-BTC","changes":{"asks":[["0","0","1613141798456"]],"bids":[]},"sequenceEnd":1613141798456}` Then It will works.. I hace updated the answer with this also

Comment: What I can observe is the problem is with your response data format, Please make sure it is correct

Comment: im trying to figure it out im just not sure what I am looking for the data im getting back is from kucoin so im not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Ok it just needed a check to see if data.data was undefined and it worked   
  if (typeof(data.data) != "undefined"){
 console.log('this ', data.data.changes)
  }